# Will Darwin Streaming Server 6.0.3 install on OS X (El Capitan)?

Tags: osx-elcapitan

Has anyone had any luck installing Darwin Streaming Server 6.0.3 on OS X 10.11.6?

I downloaded the dmg file from the site.  But when I install, this error message pops up.

*"This package is incompatible with this version of OS X and may fail to install"*

Just for kicks, I tried pressing the **Install Anyway** button but it just takes me to the next page which says "The installation failed".

Is there workarounds for this or am I out of luck?

Comment: hey! did you solved this issue???